# Extract text starting with string until space character

Tags: linux, bash, sed, grep

Sample input file

```
a   boogy                                   RqIANPGRTSSikGFb1Aoi6Q   5   1    1311234            0      1.7gb          1.7gb
a   boom                                   RqIANPGRTSSikGFb1Aoi6Q   5   1    1311234            0      1.7gb          1.7gb
a   baby                                   RqIANPGRTSSikGFb1Aoi6Q   5   1    1311234            0      1.7gb          1.7gb
a   boom                                   RqIANPGRTSSikGFb1Aoi6Q   5   1    1311234            0      1.7gb          1.7gb
```

Expected: find all words starts with **boo** and extract them from lines with `sed` or `grep` command

```
boogy
boom
boom
```

I tried:

```
$ grep -oP 'boo\K[^ ]*' input_file
gy
m
m
```

The problem here that it doesn't give the start **boo**

Comment: And on what criteria? Both start with b? Both are in the second column? Both have 4 letters? Also you should include what you have tried and explain where you're stuck and why.

Comment: Okay, I have found it:

grep -oP 'boo\K[^ ]*' 

The problem here that It doesn't give me the start "boo"

Comment: From the second field only: `awk '$2~/^boo/{print $2}' file`

Comment: just remove the `\K` (see https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/regex/639/lookahead-and-lookbehind/2462/simulating-variable-length-lookbehind-with-k#t=201705171012452043536) ... use `grep -oP 'boo[^ ]*'`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

`grep -o "\bboo[a-z]*\b" input_file`

You have to use word boundaries `\b`. Inside this boundaries you need a valid regex pattern `boo[a-z]*`.